# Python: How to get the created date and time of a folder?

Tags: python, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)

I would like to get the created date and time of a folder. Are there anyways to do that in python?

Thank you

Comment: The question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python). Check it out ;-).

Comment: And one more thing I would like to ask, for example I create a folder named "file" on 25.08.2011 at 01:58:00. When I copy this folder to other directory, its created date and time changed.So, how can I get the date and time on 25.08.2011 at 01:58:00, even when the folder is copied to other directory. :(

Answer (score 24):

You might use [`os.stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.stat) to retrieve this information.

```
os.stat(path).st_mtime      // time of most recent content modification,
os.stat(path).st_ctime      // platform dependent; time of most recent metadata change on Unix, or the time of creation on Windows)
```

Comment: And one more thing I would like to ask, for example I create a folder named "file" on 25.08.2011 at 01:58:00. When I copy this folder to other directory, its created date and time changed.So, how can I get the date and time on 25.08.2011 at 01:58:00, even when the folder is copied to other directory. :(

Comment: Thank you for the distinction between Unix and Windows with respect to st_ctime